# Transformation matrix between carthesian to spherical coordinates to draw parallel circumferences

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I've seen some algorithms with the following transformation matrix:

[image]

In such an algorithm, this matrix is used to draw some parallel circumferences on a sphere, i.e. the blue circumferences in the following figure:
[image]

Each curve is approximated as a set of points (so each circumference is approximated with a polygon). Each point is defined with the spherical coordinates $\rho, \phi, \theta$.

[image]

I want to find out some informations about this matrix. It seems to contain the classical transformation matrix from cartesian to spherical coordinates:

[image]

but it as another coloumn at right. Why has this been inserted in my matrix?

$X_c, Y_c, Z_c$ express the centre of the sphere.

Comment: Cartesian, after the Philosopher and Mathematician René Descartes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment.
The mapping $\mathbb R_+\times (-π, π)\times (0,π)\ni(r,\theta, \phi)\mapsto (x,y,z)$ is given by\begin{cases}
x=r \cos \theta\sin\phi\\
y=r \sin \theta\sin\phi\\
z=r\cos \phi
\end{cases}
and its differential is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta\sin\phi& -r \sin \theta\sin\phi&r \cos \theta\cos\phi\\
\sin \theta\sin\phi&r \cos \theta\sin\phi&r \sin \theta\cos\phi\\
\cos \phi&0&-r \sin\phi
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Permuting the second and third row, making $r=1$ you get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta\sin\phi& \cos \theta\cos\phi& - \sin \theta\sin\phi\\
\sin \theta\sin\phi& \sin \theta\cos\phi& \cos \theta\sin\phi\\
\cos \phi&- \sin\phi&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The longitude lines are defined by $\theta=\theta_0$ and the latitude lines by $\phi=\phi_0$ (the latitude is $\frac π2-\phi_0$, positive on the northern hemisphere, negative on the southern).
What was the use of your $4\times 4$ matrix?